# Defining erf(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

I know this sounds like a silly question but I saw that $erf(x)$ looked pretty similar to $\frac{2}{\pi}arctan(x)$. I tried using desmos to find the ratio between the two, and it looked like $e^{-x^{2}}$ but with a squished head and shifted vertically by 1 unit. So I tried to find the ratio of *that* and it looks pretty similar to $sec(x)$. I'm new to calculus and have just studied the basic rules of integration (u-substitution, inverse power rule, integration by parts etc) so I haven't been able to understand why $\int e^{-x^{2}}$ is non-elementary. Could someone explain?
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bqhq7khjnp
(link to desmos graphs for reference)

Comment: The error function erf is related to the normal distribution, while arctangent is related to the Cauchy distribution.  Both have bell-shaped derivatives. The Cauchy is said to have heavier tails.

Comment: Ok, but can this be related to the weird parabolic function that I observed on desmos?